# Now can't run Java on Win7 and can't execute installer

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7-x64

I had a working installation of Eclipse Neon.3 on my Win7 box.  I was running it with JDK 1.8.0_102.

For some reason I tried to install JDK 1.8.0_131 (not JRE) from the Oracle site, but it seemed to just do nothing after clicking the "Yes" on the "do you want to execute" dialog.

I decided to abort that, but now I can't even use the original 102 JDK. and when I try to run Eclipse, it just seems to ignore my request to start it.

In a DOS shell, I execute "java -version" and it gives me this:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Note that this is a JRE, not a JDK.

In that same shell, here's the beginning of PATH:

```
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;
```

That "javapath" was not put there by me.

When I look in that directory, it looks like this:

```
Directory of c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

05/05/2017  06:50 PM    <DIR>          .
05/05/2017  06:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/05/2017  06:50 PM    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_
131\bin\java.exe]
05/05/2017  06:50 PM    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0
_131\bin\javaw.exe]
05/05/2017  06:50 PM    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.
0_131\bin\javaws.exe]
```

I ran "regedit" and saw that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8 has the following:
* JavaHome: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
* RuntimeLib: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\server\jvm.dll

I seem to be unable to get this working again.  I even tried downloading and running the 102 JDK installer, and it does the same thing the 131 installer does, it just seems to ignore my request to start it.

**Update**:

Well, the comment about setting JAVA_HOME correctly sort of lead me to some goodness, but not necessarily because of what you said.  I'm well aware of the fact that JAVA_HOME needs to point to a JDK. However, I did think to verify what I have it set to, and I saw that it was referring to the 102 installation.  That should have been fine, but because of that weird "javapath" thing pointing to the 131 installation, I decided to try setting JAVA_HOME to the 131 installation.

I then restarted Eclipse, and it came up, but after some examination, I can see that this is still broken.

I'm seeing errors in the Problems view like "Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0" and "The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\sun\tools\0\tools-0.jar'".  That definitely points to running Eclipse with a JRE, not a JDK.

I then went to a DOS shell again and printed the value of JAVA_HOME:

```
JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

I then ran visualvm, opened up the Eclipse process and looked at system properties, where I saw some confusing information (some of this shortened):

```
applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
eclipse.commands=-os
win32
-ws
win32
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher
C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name
Eclipse
--launcher.library
C:\Users\<me>\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740\eclipse_1617.dll
-startup
C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\server\jvm.dll

eclipse.home.location=file:/C:/Users/<me>/eclipse/java-neon2/eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\eclipse.exe
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=file:/C:/Users/<me>/.p2/
eclipse.p2.max.threads=10
eclipse.p2.profile=C__Users_<me>_eclipse_java-neon2_eclipse
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
eclipse.startTime=1494036816583
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\server\jvm.dll
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx3072m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar

equinox.init.uuid=true
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\
gosh.args=--nointeractive
guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true
http.nonProxyHosts=dets-codereview.bodc.att.com|scm.it.att.com|localhost|127.0.0.1
http.proxyHost=one.proxy.att.com
http.proxyPort=8080
http.proxySet=true
https.nonProxyHosts=dets-codereview.bodc.att.com|scm.it.att.com|localhost|127.0.0.1
https.proxyHost=one.proxy.att.com
https.proxyPort=8080
https.proxySet=true
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path=C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
java.class.version=52.0
java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path=C:\Users\<me>\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;c:\Users\<me>\frameworks\gradle-3.5\bin;c:\Users\<me>\frameworks\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.7\groovy-2.4.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Prince\engine\bin;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Users\<me>\frameworks\jd-gui-windows-1.4.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Users\<me>\sysinternals\TcpView;C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\<me>\Desktop;;.
java.rmi.server.randomIDs=true
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_131-b11
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=25.131-b11
jnidispatch.path=C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1331751731\jna4323154665511181061.dll
line.separator=\r\n
oomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
oomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=true
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=C:\Users\<me>\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400\splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir=C:\Users\<me>\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
org.eclipse.swt.internal.deviceZoom=100
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JavaSE/compact1-1.8,JavaSE/compact2-1.8,JavaSE/compact3-1.8,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7,JavaSE-1.8
org.osgi.framework.language=en
org.osgi.framework.os.name=Windows7
org.osgi.framework.os.version=6.1.0
org.osgi.framework.processor=x86-64
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List="1.0, 1.1",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact1"; version:List="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact2"; version:List="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact3"; version:List="1.8"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=javax.accessibility,...
org.osgi.framework.uuid=83c1b397-2bd8-4102-916b-3d2d6f782fc3
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.8.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Windows 7
os.version=6.1
osgi.arch=x86_64
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.2.v201610280128.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar@1:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation.default=true
osgi.configuration.area=file:/C:/Users/<me>/eclipse/java-neon2/eclipse/configuration/
osgi.framework=file:/C:/Users/<me>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.v20170209-1843.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.2.v201610280128.jar
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.useSystemProperties=true
osgi.frameworkClassPath=., file:C:/Users/<me>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar, file:C:/Users/<me>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.2.v201610280128.jar
osgi.install.area=file:/C:/Users/<me>/eclipse/java-neon2/eclipse/
osgi.instance.area=file:/C:/Users/<me>/workspace/
osgi.instance.area.default=file:/C:/Users/<me>/workspace/
osgi.logfile=C:\Users\<me>\workspace\.metadata\.log
osgi.nl=en_US
osgi.os=win32
osgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
osgi.splashLocation=C:\Users\<me>\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400\splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=file:/C:/Users/<me>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400
osgi.syspath=c:\Users\<me>\.p2\pool\plugins
osgi.tracefile=C:\Users\<me>\workspace\.metadata\trace.log
osgi.user.area=file:/C:/Users/<me>/user/
osgi.ws=win32
path.separator=;
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\classes
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
sun.desktop=windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
svnkit.http.methods=Basic
svnkit.library.gnome-keyring.enabled=false
user.country=US
user.dir=C:\Users\<me>\Desktop
user.home=C:\Users\<me>
user.language=en
user.name=<me>
user.script=
user.timezone=America/Los_Angeles
user.variant=
```

In here you will see references to both the JDK and the JRE, even in the "eclipse.commands", most of the value of which is from my "eclipse.ini" file, which only has ONE "-vm" parameter, referring to the 131 JDK (not the JRE).

The funny thing is, I don't even understand how it successfully installed the 131 JDK at all, because when I executed that installer, I clicked the "Yes" button to run the installer, but it never brought up an additional dialog.  It seems like it did all of that in the background.

**Update**:

Uninstalling the 131 JDK and reinstalling it seemed like a good idea.  Unfortunately, it appeared to make no difference in the result.  After uninstalling and reinstalling, the result from "java -version" hasn't changed, I still get the error about the missing "tools" artifact in Eclipse, and visualvm still seems to think I'm using the JRE, not the JDK.

Curiously, the contents of the "javapath" directory is now different.  Instead of symbolic links, they are now "hard files" with the same names.

**Update**:

I just tried uninstalling both the JDK and JRE of 131 and 102, then running the 102 JDK installer.  I set the "-vm" argument in the eclipse.ini file to point to the 102 installation.  I set JAVA_HOME to point to the 102 distribution.  I restarted Eclipse.  Exact same error.  I then inspected the "javapath" directory again, and now they're symlinks again, pointing to the JRE executables, not the JDK executables.  I also reran visualvm and verified that the "java.home" property in the Eclipse process is the JRE, not the JDK.

I'm mystified.

Comment: Did you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable? I saw your Javahome is point to jre, it's not true, JAVA_HOME must point to jdk folder

Comment: It is always possible the installer itself has an issue. I seem to recall a Java release for Windows not that long ago that had some particular hang-up. You might try uninstalling all of the Java instances and trying again.